# how to print the root invoke class name of the invoke?

Tags: java, log4j2

In log4j2, there are 2 classes:

**Common.java**

```
public class Common {
    protected static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("mts_logger");

    public static void sayHi(String hi){
        logger.info(hi);
    }
}
```

Demo1.java:

```
public class Demo1 {
    @Test
    public void test1(){
        Common.sayHi("hello");
    }
}
```

and the printed log is :

```
2021-04-09 12:10:27.652  INFO   -utils.Common.sayHi(Common.java:14) mts_logger  Common.java - world
```

the log4j2.xml pattern is:

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level  -%l %c - %msg%n" />
```

We could see that the log only print Common.java, did not print the class name of Demo1  , I just want that the log could show the original class name which invoked the method "sayHi", in this example, the class name is Demo1.
How to config log4j2  then it could show the "**original**" invoke class name "Demo1" too ?

In one word, how to make it to print Demo1  in the log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `Common.java` like this:

```
package com.mypackage;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocatorUtil;

class Common {
    protected static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("mts_logger");

    public static void sayHi(String msg){
        //using API available in log4j get the caller location
        //use Fully qualified name of the Common class.
        StackTraceElement ste = StackLocatorUtil.calcLocation("com.mypackage.Common"); 
        

        logger.info(ste.toString() + ": " + msg);
    }
}
```

With your current pattern it'll log like this:

```
2021-04-09 11:08:37.230 INFO   -Common.sayHi(Test.java:20) -sayHi mts_logger - Demo1.test1(Test.java:26): hello
```

You can remove `-%l` to avoid printing `-Common.sayHi(Test.java:20) -sayHi`

Answer (score 1):

Although you have accepted Onkar's answer that is not the best way to do it. There are two better ways depending on what you are doing.

1. Creating a Logger "wrapper". Log4j actually does this itself in a few places for example, the [Log4jLogger](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/release-2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/slf4j/Log4jLogger.java) that binds SLF4J to Log4J. If you look at that class you will see it declare a variable named FQCN. This is set to the name of the wrapper class and then gets passed to all the Logger methods. Log4j will use this to find the stack frame that called that class. This will cause you to continue to use your existing pattern but have the correct class name. This is similar to Onkar's answer but it uses a logging method that accepts the FQCN, so you don't have to format the stack trace element yourself.
2. You just have a need to include the caller for this one thing. For that use the LogBuilder that was added in Log4j 2.13.0. For this you should do:

   ```
   package com.mypackage;

   import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
   import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
   import org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocatorUtil;

   public class Common {
       protected static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("mts_logger");

       public static void sayHi(String msg) {          
           StackTraceElement ste = StackLocatorUtil.getStackTraceElement(3); 
           logger.atInfo().withLocation(ste).log(msg);
       }
   }
   ```

As in the first option, this will also cause Log4j to include the correct class, line and method information when including those in your pattern. If you are using Java 11 you can use StackWalker instead of Log4j's StackLocatorUtil.

The number being passed to getStackTraceElement is the number of levels up it needs to go for the relevant stack frame. A value of 1 would yield the frame for StackLocatorUtil. A value of 2 would return the stack frame for the call to StackLocatorUtil in SayHi, and a value of 3 should be the caller of sayHi. This method is much faster than searching for the FQCN but that is the only option when you don't know the number of stack frames.

Comment: Thank you , now I am using  MDC which provided by logback :)